# Python - Print Webscrape onto excel

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code prints data fine.

Traditionally I would have the output in a dictionary which would be converted to a DataFrame and then into excel.

However, because I am pulling data from different parts of the html/website, and I cannot use this method.

How would I be able to print the output of these 2 blocks of data into Excel?

Outputs - **Title**, **m**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.youtube.com/user/AbbVie/videos'
driver.get(url)
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
content=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')

for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
metas=soup.find_all('span',class_='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
for m in metas:
    print(m.text)
`
```

Comment: have you seen openpyxl or xlsxwriter libraries? check their docs. I have personally used xlsxwriter and it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Id want to put both of this data into the same excel. Would these libraries allow this?

Comment: yes of course, it will allow way more than that